# Запятые в простых предложениях с уточнениями

Tags: пунктуация

Простые предложения:

1. Поехал Вася в Александровку к сестре денег занять.
2. Поехал Вася к сестре в Александровку денег занять.

Я и сам всегда писал подобные предложения без запятых. Но ведь "к сестре" или "в Александровку" могут быть уточнениями (Александровка - обстоятельство места, но ведь "к сестре"  тоже можно принять как обстоятельство места или нет? Ведь имеется в виду "к сестре домой").

3. Поехал Вася в город, на рынок, порося продавать.
4. Поехал Вася на рынок, в город, порося продавать.

Нужны ли запятые в 1-м и 2-м примерах, а может, и в 3-м и 4-м ?

Answer (score 3):

> > Я и сам всегда писал подобные предложения без запятых

И правильно.

> > Но ведь "к сестре" или "в Александровку" могут быть уточнениями

Притянуть за уши что хочешь можно.

Я бы и в третьем не ставил, хотя в нем и можно. А четвертое плоховато построено, нет смысла и обсуждать. Сначала все-таки в город, а потом на рынок.

Comment: Полностью согласна. Поехал Вася в город, на рынок, порося продавать. - уточнение, от широкого к узкому, вернее уточняющее пояснение, потому что здесь уточнять не требуется, автор сам захотел внести уточняющий смысл, пояснить, хотя и без запятых всё понятно. Есть такие любители всё усложнять, уточнять, пояснять, это так называемое авторское. Не ошибка, но и надобности  в этом нет.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере "к сестре" - определение( к кому? - к сестре ), а не обстоятельство место. Запятые не нужны. В и в 3-м и 4-м уточняющие об-ва, запятые нужны.

Comment: Серж, ну какое же это определение? Вы вообще про части речи или  про члены предложения рассуждаете? Хотя, конечно, на любые вопросы - даем любые ответы.

Comment: behemothus , если честно, я вас не понял. При чем тут член предложения или части речи?

Comment: Вот я Вас не понял. Ответить можете на мой вопрос?

Comment: Да, задавайте..

Comment: Так задал уже. Вы вообще про части речи или про члены предложения рассуждаете?

Comment: Серж хотел сказать не "определение", а "дополнение" - к кому?- к сестре. Это так. Но и обстоятельство места тоже - это дуплексив.

Comment: А-а, да, конечно. только о частях речи разговора не было

Answer (score 0):

Во всех приведенных примерах возможно авторское решение, то есть авторская воля и авторский стиль. В некоторых случаях постановка запятых и членение предложения на части может быть связано с особой разговорной манерой рассказчика.

А как  определить возможность авторского решения? Парный вариант с авторским выбором возможен в том случае, когда нет четкой границы в различении обстоятельств, и тогда автор может их   представить и как НЕОДНОРОДНЫЕ, и как УТОЧНЯЮЩИЕ.  Кроме того,  возможность обособления зависит от структуры и распространенности предложения.

Примеры:
1) Неоднородные обстоятельства, разные признаки:

За рекой на горе лес зелёный стоит. Далеко на восток тянутся горные хребты. 
Летом в дождливую погоду здесь скучно.

2) Сужение значения, уточняющие обстоятельства:

За рекой, в розовеющем небе, ярко сверкала вечерняя звезда. Летом, вечерними зорями, на вершину кургана прилетает беркут. За рекой, на высокой горе, одиноко темнеет лес.